# Convolutional neural network with cross validation in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cross-validation, convolutional-neural-network

I want to use K-fold cross-validation on my dataset of images. I am reading the data (images) from a directory.

How do I use cross validation with convolutional neural network in Keras?

Comment: You might find that data generation (slightly modifying your data to increase your dataset) produces better results than k-fold cross-validation, particularly with images. The only trick is you have to make sure your modifications don't change the labels.

Comment: I tried `ImageDataGenerator` and I want to try k-fold cross-validation to see its results.